# Drawer button to toggle enable/disable lock screen

Tags: lock-screens, user-interface

I am looking for a way to enable the addition of a button in the android drawer which acts as a toggle for enabling/disabling the lock screen. I want to use it to toggle lock screen on when I have to put the phone in my pocket, and lock screen on when I leave the phone on my desk.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! Someone developed an app which enables you to lock the screen by tapping a notification drawer entry or in several other ways. The app can be found on the play store. Here it is:

[Screen Lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iglint.android.screenlock)

[Screen Lock Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iglint.android.screenlockpro)

Regards.